# How to politely follow up your prospective manager?

Tags: word-choice

I wish to ask from my prospective manager if she could find some time to speak with a third party.

So, is the following sentence fine and polite?

> I wish to ask if you have spoken to [third party]

Any other suggestion that does the job politely, works for me

Comment: You need to indicate what the proposed meeting is about. And your suggested sentence is not fine. The sentence assumes that the manager knows about the third party and may already have spoken to this person. But your introduction says you want to ask her if she might find time to speak to this person in future. You need to clarity the situation.

Comment: ***to** politely **follow up*** not "to follow**ing** up".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polite way to ask your prospective manager whether she followed up:

> Have you **had a chance** to follow up with X?
>
> Have you **had an opportunity** to follow up with X?
>
> Have you **been able** to follow up with X?

What makes it polite is that the question makes oblique reference to the possibility that she may have been busy with other matters. There is thus a slight  obeisance but no servility in the question as posed.